# SQL CASE WHEN Logic does not work for comparison to NOW() date

Tags: sql, database, apache-phoenix

I am using Apache Phoenix Query Server. I need to manipulate the `payment_status` column so that it follows the logic below and be corrected.

However, I noticed that even when `paid_date` is equal to `now_date`, the converted status (`new_payment_status`) becomes "Overdue" instead of "Due". Any ideas why was that happening?

```
SELECT paid_date, TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(paid_date)), NOW() AS now_date, payment_status AS old_payment_status, 
(CASE WHEN (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(paid_date)) = NOW()) THEN 'Due'
    WHEN (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(paid_date)) < NOW()) THEN 'Overdue'
    WHEN (TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(paid_date)) > NOW()) THEN 'Paid' 
ELSE 'No Status'
END) as new_payment_status
FROM utilities_table WHERE bill='123';
```

**Result and Metadata:**

*Edit: Embeded a screenshot instead, because markdown for tables aren't translating properly.*

[Result and Metadata Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gDfJ.png)

Since I'm really not that familiar with Phoenix Query Server, I tried to read how does TO_DATE and NOW() works.

Found that there are also other parameters for TO_DATE, and thought it could be because of the timezone. 
https://phoenix.apache.org/language/functions.html#to_date

https://phoenix.apache.org/language/functions.html#now

However, that wouldn't really make sense because as you could see from the result of the query above -- that was the value it retrieved and was trying to compare. I also thought it may be because they have different data types, but as per the metadata, they're both DATEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you convert `paid_date` to a String, you are changing its format, which does not include the time component.

Also, date comparison only returns true if both dates are exactly equal.

Therefore, `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(paid_date)) = NOW()` never works.

Try using `TRUNC(paid_date) = TRUNC(NOW())` if the time doesn't matter for you, or `paid_date = NOW()` if you want to check the time as well."

Comment: Thank you! This worked. However, TRUNC needs to have a parameter for day, such as `TRUNC(paid_date, 'DAY')`. More details [here](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/functions.html#trunc)